# How to sign javascript to prevent "To help protect your security..." ActiveX/script warning bar

Tags: javascript, security, certificate, code-signing, digital-certificate

Is there any way to sign your javascript code to prevent the IE8 security bar from displaying?
With a digital certificate or something similar?

[Edit]

The error is just the plain old

> To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.  Click here for options...

Options are

> Allow Blocked Content...
>
> What's the Risk
>
> Information Bar Help

To add a little more context, I am using practically one line of javascript to solve the CSS problem with having multiple columns dynamically sized to content.  I've been pulling my hair out to figure that one out and ended up using javascript because it was much easier and more straightforward.  However, it is overkill to have an information bar pop-down for just one line of javascript changing the formatting of a page.  I know they can add this to their safe sites, or even just click "Allow Blocked Content", but it would be nice if they didn't have to deal with this for something so trivial.

Comment: Whatever IE8 security bar you are seeing isn't because of your javascript as there is no way to sign javascript that I'm aware of.  Can you describe the security warning more and give us a link that we can look at?

Comment: It's just the plain old "to help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.  Click here for options..."

Comment: That sounds like your IE8 is configured to not run scripts on the public internet.  That's an IE8 feature that you can change the configuration for.  It is likely working as designed.  I don't know of any way to sign scripts (unless there's a Microsoft-only way to do so).  There is a way to sign ActiveX plug-ins.

Comment: How about showing us the code and a screenshot of the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Add the site you're using to test on to the list of trusted sites in IE.

Comment: This is fine for the test box, but what about production deployment?  The goal is that the users do not ever see this box.  The box is a security feature, so I was wondering if there was some sort of signing available for javascript code.